# ul styling in firefox and IE

Tags: css

I have this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/rd2Hc/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/rd2Hc/)

when  clicked in IE gets a dotted border around the li in IE but does not happen in Firefox..Is there a way we can get that in firefox.

```
<ul>
    <li>
     <a tabIndex="-1" class="ui" id="ui-id-17"  href="#tabs-1">
         Content
         </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a tabIndex="-1" class="ui" id="A1" href="#tabs-1">
            People
         </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a tabIndex="-1" class="ui" id="A2" href="#tabs-1">
            Test
         </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. With the property `outline` and the states for your a tag `active or focus` just put this lines in your Css

```
a:active, a:focus {
   outline:#00FF00 dotted thin; /*Change the values that you want*/
}
```

You can see this running here http://jsfiddle.net/rd2Hc/7/

Comment: Thank u ..that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

The dotted border is because of the default `outline` property in CSS. You can modify the outline property to do so:

```
a:active, a:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/rd2Hc/12/

Comment: Sorry for not being clear ..I have edited my question..I actually want the dotted line to come up in firefox like it comes up in IE